# share extension error in xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So i update Xcode to Xcode 7.1 but in my share extension i got one error :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
>        reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'ExtensionInterface' in bundle NSBundle

but in my info.split i have the `NSExtensionMainStoryboard` with the name of the storyboard extension

[image]

I deleted the extension and created another one but I still get the same error. I don't know if it is a Xcode 7.1 bug, because everything worked well in Xcode 6.4

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently it is a Xcode bug, I figured out that Clean Build Folder ( <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> ) and then just clean ( <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> ) every time before run my app, and  my share extesion works fine.